# CAPL samples for GPIB(type VISA / E3648A)?

Tags: capl, gpib

Today I created the E3648A control type GPIB.
But my code did not work properly.

I try Devonline.
The return value is 0x01xx.

Output command sent.
But it does not work.

I want to see a sample or an example.
help me

`long status;`

`char command[49];`

`status = GPIBDevOnline (Device_ID,0);`

`//status = 0x128;`

`command[0] = 0xxx;`

...
`command[48] = 0x0a;`

`GPIBWriteStr (Device_ID,command);`

`

Answer (score 0):

File tab → Sample Configurations → IO HIL → General Purpose Inter Bus
or Search GPIB.cfg